# KML Writing - Points are showing up in Left Pane of Google Earh, But not On On Map Layer

Tags: kml

I have this kml script that I am using to place "arrow" icons in Google Earth. The idea is the icons will highlight when passed over with the cursor.

The knl loads without error into GE, and white icons show in the left pane (Places"), but not on the actual map. There is no highlighting going on anywhere. My cursor is a big hand now in GE. I have no properties when I right click for properties of an icon in the left pane.

Where did I go wrong in my code that has made the icons invisible and inaccessible?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
          <Document>
            <name>729A</name>
            <description></description>
            <Style id="highlightPlacemark">
              <IconStyle>
                <color>ff00aaff</color>
                <scale>0.6</scale>
                <Icon>
                  <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/arrow.png</href>
                </Icon>
              </IconStyle>
            </Style>
            <Style id="normalPlacemark">
              <IconStyle>
                <color>ff0000ff</color>
                <scale>0.6</scale>
                <Icon>
                  <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/arrow.png</href>
                </Icon>
              </IconStyle>
            </Style>
            <StyleMap id="arrows1StyleMap">
              <Pair>
                <key>normal</key>
                <styleUrl>#normalPlacemark</styleUrl>
              </Pair>
              <Pair>
                <key>highlight</key>
                <styleUrl>#highlightPlacemark</styleUrl>
              </Pair>
            </StyleMap>
    <Placemark>
          <name></name>
          <description></description>
          <styleUrl>#arrows1StyleMap</styleUrl>
          <point>
            <coordinates>-80.54005,43.46324,0</coordinates>
          </point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
          <name></name>
          <description></description>
          <styleUrl>#arrows1StyleMap</styleUrl>
          <point>
            <coordinates>-80.54005,43.46324,0</coordinates>
          </point>
        </Placemark>
 </Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check for basic errors in your KML, you can use this KML validator:
http://www.kmlvalidator.org
(the site currently appears to be down, but usually works great)

It does strict schema validation, so will catch important errors, as well as lots of nit picky stuff which most KML clients (including Google Earth) don't really care about.

Answer (score 1):

It appears I have made several mistakes with regards to appropriate capitalization.

For example ...
Capitalization of "Point" is critical.